# Fragment Deprecated. What to use instead? Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, deprecated

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/Fragment) page Fragment is deprecated. So, what is to be used instead of Fragments from API 28 on?

A tabbed activity used to depend on Fragments. What is the new way for tabbed activities?

Comment: @cutiko According to [this page](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library) "The AndroidX library contains the existing support library and also includes the latest Jetpack components." Looks like there is no reason not to switch to AndroidX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the error message, only the framework `android.app.Fragment` classes are deprecated. The [AndroidX Fragments](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment) are not deprecated and are continuing to have new releases.

Answer (score 1):

First add this `Fragment` `dependency` in your project- [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#declaring_dependencies)

> Then just Replace  `<fragment` with
> `<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView`

Here is auto generated suggestion by Android Studio.
[image]